# Java swing component instantiation

Tags: java, swing

Recently while developing a swing application somebody told me to use `(ComponentClassName) Beans.instantiate(MyClass.class.getClassLoader(), ComponentClassName.class.getName())` to create component object instead of using "new". I would like to know the right approach.

Comment: Why would you do that? Doesn't make sense. Use new.

Comment: @JB Nizet-Thanks for your answer. By the way someone told me that the above approach will work faster, I had a doubt on it. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: It will go slower actually. The code uses reflection to call `new ComponentClassName()`. Reflection calls are slower than direct calls, are not typesafe, are longer, are less readable, and do the exact same thing in the end.

Comment: @JB Nizet-Is there any memory concern with this?

Comment: Understod. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Beans.instantiate() if the type you want to instantiate is chosen dynamically. Generally the new keyword works just fine, and is what I always use in Swing applications.

Answer (score 1):

I think the right approach will be to use the new keyword, after all, that's it's role. The way you are using Beans seems a bit forced since you know what type of class you wish to instantiate. Second, since this is a swing application, most probably you are using default swing classes (maybe extending some of them). Another problem with this approach is that you must have a constructor without args in your class.
Class.forName() can be used for the same thing as the code above, but if you don't want to dynamically create a class at runtime, stick with the new keyword.